# CSS issue with percentage margin for vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, webkit

### My problem is:

I want to have an overlayed box (which in the example is the dashed bordered div) that is centered within a larger background content (which in my case is a google map which in the example is indicated by the blue background.

I am using Chrome (latest version) and am finding that I can do what I want (sort of) but I am doing it in a way that doesn't quite work when resizing the screen horizontally, ie the margin on the top (ie the distance between the dashed line and the top of the blue box) seems the change its vertical distance as compared to the width of the screen (which is very strange to me).

### The code is:

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 100px; display: block; background-color: green">
   <div style="background-color: blue; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%">b</div>
   <div style="border-width: 2px; border-style: dashed; margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%; width: 90%; height: 90%; position: absolute"></div>  
</div>
```

[A JS fiddle example of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/448DC/)

From what I read, there is [some information](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) talking about the parent block determining the height etc, but I'm a bit lost as there seems to be a piece of knowledge I am missing, and my approach is probably entirely wrong as to how I am trying to go about doing this. I really don't wanna specify height or width programmatically, but the width seems to work in a scalable way.

Comment: `margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;` could be shortened to `margin: 5%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin in percents is related **to width**, so just set top, left, right, bottom properties.

```
<div style="top: 5%; left: 5%; right: 5%; bottom: 5%; position:absolute"></div>
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Answer (score 1):

you can use this style for your border:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/448DC/1/)

```
#border{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dashed;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    position: absolute;
}
```